# Joda DateTime Format for XMLGregorianCalendar Type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using JAXB 2.2.8-b01 impl and I have a schema which has a xs:date element which creates a XMLGregorianCalendar instance.  I'm trying to get a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) timestamp format but since I have to have a XMLGregorianCalendar instance, I'm not sure its possible.  Any ideas?

**Schema XSD:**

```
<xs:element type="xs:date" name="date-archived" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false"/>
```

**JAXB Generated Property:**

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar date;
```

**XML Conversion Class:**

```
//java.util.Date being passed


private XMLGregorianCalendar converToGregorianCal(Date date) {
    DatatypeFactory df = null;
    try {
        df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        LOG.error("error getting DatatypeFactory instance " + e.getMessage()); 
    }
    if (date == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
        return df.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). `myXMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toString()`

Comment: @BasilBourque True, as long you're using Java 8. With legacy Java 7 (or 6 or 5) the Joda-Time is the best way.

Comment: @рüффп Much of the *java.time* functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. When you eventually move to Java 8 or later, you’ll need do little more than switch your `import` statements.

Comment: Thanks to pointing to this back-port. I wasn't aware of this. That would make the transition to Java 8 smoother.

Answer (score 13):

This is a short way:

```
public DateTime convert(final XMLGregorianCalendar xmlgc) {
    return new DateTime(xmlgc.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Below is how you can have `xs:date` correspond to Joda-Time `DateTime` being generated into the class model.

### XML Schema

Below is an XML Schema with two elements of type `xs:date`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="root">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="foo" type="date"/>
                <element name="bar" type="date"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>

</schema>
```

### Binding `xs:date` to Joda-Time `DateTime`

An external binding document can be used to customize the class generation, below is what you would need to do to generate Joda-Time `DateTime` for `xs:date`.  The binding document is referenced using the `-b` flag to XJC.

```
xjc -b binding.xml schema.xsd
```

**Bind All Instances**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="2.1"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <!-- use JODA-Time DateTime for xs:date -->
        <jxb:javaType name="org.joda.time.DateTime" xmlType="xs:date"
            parseMethod="com.example.MyConverter.parseDate"
            printMethod="com.example.MyConverter.printDate"/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>        
</jxb:bindings>
```

**Bind One Instance**

The binding file below will cause the `foo` element to use `DateTime` but not the `bar` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='foo']">
            <jxb:property>
                <jxb:baseType>
                    <jxb:javaType 
                       name="org.joda.time.DateTime" 
                       parseMethod="com.example.MyConverter.parseDate" 
                       printMethod="com.example.MyConverter.printDate" />
                </jxb:baseType>
            </jxb:property>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

### com.example.MyConverter

This is where you put your logic to convert a `String` to from `DateTime`:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class MyConverter {

    public static String printDate(DateTime value) {
        // TODO - Conversion Logic
    }

    public static DateTime parseDate(String value) {
       // TODO - Conversion Logic
    }

}
```

### For More Information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/xml-schema-to-java-generating.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

Comment: There is this link that helped: http://azagorneanu.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/configure-maven-to-generate-classes.html

Answer (score 4):

Unclear from the question but if you want `XMLGregorianCalendar` from JodaTime `DateTime`, then this is possible:

```
final GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(dateTime.getZone().toTimeZone());
calendar.setTimeInMillis(dateTime.getMillis());
return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
```

Comment: And `XMLGregorianCalendarImpl` comes from where?

Comment: XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.

## DateTime?

If you have a java.util.Date, you can easily convert that to a Joda-Time DateTime:

1. Pass the Date instance to constructor of a DateTime.
2. Pass a DateTimeZone instance to the same constructor.

While a `java.util.Date` has no time zone assigned (it represents UTC/GMT, without any time zone offset), an [`org.joda.time.DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) does indeed know its own time zone. If you want your DateTime to have UTC/GMT instead of a specific time zone, use the built-in constant [`DateTimeZone.UTC`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#UTC).

```java
java.util.Date someDate = new java.util.Date();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( someDate, DateTimeZone.UTC );

// Or, a specific time zone.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTimeParis = new DateTime( someDate, timeZone );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTimeParis: " + dateTimeParis );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2014-01-22T22:39:03.996Z
dateTimeParis: 2014-01-22T23:39:03.996+01:00
```

Passing the Date instance, it's just that easy. You could extract from the Date instance it's number of milliseconds since the [Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) [Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29), and pass that `long` number to DateTime. But no need, as the DateTime class is willing to that work.

## String?

Or by “timestamp format” did you mean you want an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted string like this: `2014-01-19T12:38.301Z`? That string format is the default for a DateTime's `toString` method.

```java
String isoString = new DateTime( someDate, DateTimeZone.UTC ).toString();
```

Comment: I guess the real requirement is to have an iso supported date format in the resulting xml file generated from my schema.

Answer (score 0):

We have faced this and after spending time with formatters found a simplest solution

```
String sf = xmlGregDate.toString()
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(sf)
```

This was a life savour.

Answer (score -3):

Be very careful with JodaTime, the lib don't use the timezone tables of java.

```
public class XMLCalendarToDateTime {

    private static DatatypeFactory df = null;
    static {
        try {
            df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException dce) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Exception while obtaining DatatypeFactory instance", dce);
        }
    }  

    private static XMLGregorianCalendar converToGregorianCal(DateTime dateTime) {
        if (dateTime == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
            gc.setTimeInMillis(dateTime.getMillis());
            return df.newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
        }
    }

    private static DateTime convertToDateTime(XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar){
         if (xmlGregorianCalendar == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return new DateTime(xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2014,1,1,1,1);

        System.out.println("date = " + dateTime.toString());

        final XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = converToGregorianCal(dateTime);

        System.out.println("xmlGregorianCalendar = " + xmlGregorianCalendar);

        final DateTime dateTimeConverted = convertToDateTime(xmlGregorianCalendar);

        System.out.println("dateTimeConverted = "  + dateTimeConverted);

    }
}
```

Comment: True, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) does not use the time zone data files bundled with Java. Instead it uses its own copy of the [standard tz database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones). Java does not often update its tables, whereas Joda-Time does. Furthermore, you can easily [update or tweak the tables](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/tz_update.html) in Joda-Time as needed for occasional changes made by government bodies at the last minute. The time zone data is yet another good reason to use Joda-Time rather than the bundled java.util.Date/Calendar classes.

Comment: These converter methods discards the time-zone information. Consider creating the calendar objects with time-zone: `new GregorianCalendar(dateTime.getZone().toTimeZone())`